# Page with button grouping row

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a page with gridview, with grouping row. When I update information via ajax in the second gridview, information refreshed after clicking on the button Plus, minus. 
**How I can update data inside second grid without clicking on Plus-minus?** [image]

Code where I show and close gridview inside another gridview.

```
$('.glyphicon-plus').click(function (event) {
                    if ($(this).hasClass("glyphicon-plus"))
                        $(this).closest("tr").after("<tr><td></td><td colspan = '999'>" + $(this).next().html() + "</td></tr>");
                    else
                        $(this).closest("tr").next().remove();
                    $(this).toggleClass('glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus');});
```

Code gridview

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" Style="display: none" Visible="true"><ContentTemplate><asp:GridView ID="grdId" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass = "ChildGrid" Width="100%" OnRowDataBound="grdId_RowDataBound" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"><Columns></Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

ajax method

```
var thisCell=this.value;var id=this.id; $.ajax({type: \"POST\",url: \"myPage.aspx/myMethod\",data: '{value:\"'+comment+'\",id:\"'+id+'\"}',
    contentType: \"application/json; charset=utf-8\",
    dataType: \"json\",success: function(response) {}});
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved problem via JS, 
on load, I am using a script for changing my architecture gridview.

```
$('#MainContent_GridView > tbody  > tr').each(function () {
                     var div1 = $(this).find('.hideGroup');
                     $(this).find('.hideGroup').remove();
                     var row = $('<tr>').append($('<td>')).append($('<td colspan = "999">').append(div1));
                     $(row).insertAfter($(this).closest('tr'));
                 });
```

And changed on event click code.

```
$('.glyphicon-plus').click(function (event) {var thisHG = $(this).closest("tr").next().find('.hideGroup');
                    console.log(thisHG);
                    thisHG.toggle();
                    $(this).toggleClass('glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus');
}
```